# SQL Association on product items based on User ID

Tags: sql

Here's an example dataset:

```
    | user_id | product_id | dt       | quantity | price
    | 1       | a          |2017-05-20| 2        | 3.95
    | 1       | b          |2017-06-02| 7        | 19.95
    | 2       | a          |2017-06-23| 4        | 5.99
    | 2       | b          |2017-04-03| 2        | 19.95
    | 2       | c          |2017-06-08| 1        | 9.99
    | 3       | a          |2017-07-02| 4        | 4.98
    | 3       | c          |2017-06-05| 3        | 18.95
```

Give a SQL query that returns pairs of items (ie pairs of `item_id`s) and counts the number of users that have ordered that item at least once (for the sake of simplicity, we won't take frequency of orders or quantity of items bought into account--just whether or not a user bought a given item). For the example data above, the output should be:

```
    | item_id_1 | item_id_2 | num_users |
    | a         | b         | 2         |
    | a         | c         | 2         |
    | b         | c         | 1         |
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: This looks like a homework exercise. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? What is your question?

Comment: I am using SQL.

Comment: I am doing this;
select a.product_id as item_id_1, b.product_id as item_id_2, COUNT(*) num_users
from  orders a join orders b
on a.user_id = b.user_id
and a.product_id != b.product_id
group by a.product_id, b.product_id
order by num_users desc

Comment: thats running now thanks, the one above.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a self-join:

```
select e.product_id, e2.product_id as product_id_2,
       count(distinct e.user_id) as num_users
from example e join
     example e2
     on e.user_id = e2.user_id
group by e.product_id, e2.product_id
order by num_users desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.product_id as item_id_1, b.product_id as item_id_2, COUNT(*) num_users 
from orders a 
join orders b 
on a.user_id = b.user_id and a.product_id < b.product_id 
group by a.product_id, b.product_id 
order by num_users desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming users can order the same product more than once, it's best to group the users and products first.

Then those 2 grouped results are joined on the same user_id and a different product_id.
In this case a lower product_id, because we only want f.e. the combination 'a' & 'b' and not also it's reverse combination 'b' & 'a'.

After that, it just needs to be grouped with a count.

```
select 
 t1.product_id as item_id_1, 
 t2.product_id as item_id_2, 
 count(t1.user_id) as num_users
from 
(
    select user_id, product_id 
    from YourTable
    group by user_id, product_id
) t1
join (
    select user_id, product_id 
    from YourTable 
    group by user_id, product_id
) t2 on (t1.user_id = t2.user_id and t1.product_id < t2.product_id)
group by t1.product_id, t2.product_id
order by t1.product_id, t2.product_id
```

If your database supports the WITH clause then you can put that same subquery in a common table expression and re-use it.

```
WITH CTE as (
    select user_id, product_id 
    from YourTable
    group by user_id, product_id
)
select 
 t1.product_id as item_id_1, 
 t2.product_id as item_id_2, 
 count(t1.user_id) as num_users
from CTE t1
join CTE t2 on (t1.user_id = t2.user_id and t1.product_id < t2.product_id)
group by t1.product_id, t2.product_id
order by t1.product_id, t2.product_id
```